# codeignighter routes not working in vagrant

Tags: php, codeigniter, vagrant

I have setup a vagrant environment of my website so that I can work offline. I've set port 80 to go to 8080 on my pc in the vagrant file and can access the local site homepage ok, @ "http://192.168.1.10:8080".

The issue I have is that routes are not working, I have modrewrite enabled on apache and have a htaccess file. I also edited my config.php file but still I get 404 file not found when I try to access other pages. Have I missed something obvious?

Config.php =

```
$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url']= $root;
```

.htaccess =

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.well-known) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.well-known) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Route example =

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['customer'] = 'customer/login/login';
$route['products'] = 'Home/products'
```

I have enabled mod rewrite logging and I get this, as if its just passing on what it gets:

```
[Sun Sep 02 08:34:32.836789 2018] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 15927] 
mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.0.2.2:52113] 10.0.2.2 - - 
[192.168.1.10/sid#7f71dfca45c8][rid#7f71dfc030a0/initial] init rewrite 
engine with requested uri /products
[Sun Sep 02 08:34:32.836830 2018] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 15927] 
mod_rewrite.c(476): [client 10.0.2.2:52113] 10.0.2.2 - - 
[192.168.1.10/sid#7f71dfca45c8][rid#7f71dfc030a0/initial] pass through 
/products
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?  Is it apache errors and or browser errors?

Comment: Just browser error, there is no apache error. Just the access log that shows 404 not found.